# Filtering dataextension row by Date

Tags: date, marketing-cloud

I am attempting to filter a dataExtension row by date.
The column I am trying to access has a Date fieldtype and uses the current date as a default.
An example of one of the values is: 10/24/2013 5:32 AM in the ET GUI.
I am coding in python but cannot seem to be able to retrieve the rows I need.
I have tried multiple combinations, using 'Value' and 'DateValue'

```
debug = True
stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)
row = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Row()
row.auth_stub = stubObj
row.CustomerKey = de_name
row.props = de_fields
row.search_filter = {'Property' : 'ImportDate', 'SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : '10/24/2013 5:32 AM'}
getResponse = row.get()
print 'Results: ' + str(getResponse.results)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is ImportDate set as the name of the property in ET. if yes, please try using any other operator (such as GREATER_THAN, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL) which could give you the same result and see if it works for ya

Comment: Have you been able to get this working?

Comment: So it turns out that I was able to achieve my goal by using a complex filter. The leftOperand looks for rows with a date greaterOrEqual to the date I'm looking for. The rightOperand looks for rows with a date strictly lessThan the date I'm looking for + 1 day. The conjunction of both filters artificially creates an "equal" operator. I'm not sure why the equals operator isn't working in this case but at least I'm able to get the results I want. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: You should set this as the answer, and mark it as "answered" so we know it has a solution :)

Comment: Would you mind answering this so the community can benefit - right now it's left open and is not very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert the time into server time. For example in a soap call:

```
<Property>CreatedDate</Property>
<SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
<DateValue>2010-11-15T11:25:54.617-07:00</DateValue>
```

I've not fully tested the filter in the SDK, but DateValue seems appropriate here, based on how they are built.